# Segment out large file by specific unique word in line and remove duplicates within those segements using Python or any other scriping language

Tags: php, python, regex, bash, unix

I'll try to get right to the point. So I'm trying to segment out a large exported file (400MB's) by a specific word. We'll say the unique word in this example is `PYTHONEXP`.

Example:

```
XXXXX PYTHONEXP xxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxx 12.34.34.34 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
xxxx 12.34.34.34 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

XXXXX PYTHONEXP xxxxxx
xxxxxxx 55.44.44.44 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxx 55.44.44.44 xxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

XXXXX PYTHONEXP xxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxx 77.66.66.66 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxx 77.66.66.66 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

XXXXX PYTHONEXP xxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx 99.88.88.88 xxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxx 99.88.88.88xxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

XXXXX PYTHONEXP xxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxx 22.33.33.33 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxx 22.33.33.33 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

XXXXX PYTHONEXP xxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx 99.88.88.88 xxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxx 99.88.88.88 xxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Now, let's pretend the x's are random words, but each chunk shares the unique word (`PYTHONEXP`) at the very beginning. I want to be able to segment each portion and remove the duplicate IP's *within* those segments only. Ideally, I'd like an output like this:

```
XXXXX PYTHONEXP xxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxx 12.34.34.34 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
xxxx  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

XXXXX PYTHONEXP xxxxxx
xxxxxxx 55.44.44.44 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxx  xxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

XXXXX PYTHONEXP xxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxx 77.66.66.66 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxx  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

XXXXX PYTHONEXP xxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx 99.88.88.88 xxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxx xxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

XXXXX PYTHONEXP xxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxx 22.33.33.33 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxx  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

XXXXX PYTHONEXP xxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx 99.88.88.88 xxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxx  xxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Notice how I still have 2 entries for `99.88.88.88` in my desired output instead of 4. My main goal is to have the duplicates removed ***within*** these segments based on lines that simply contain `PYTHONEXP`. I would GREATLY appreciate any help on this or know if this is even possible. I hope I explained this right or it makes sense.

Comment: explode on PYTHONEXP, loop those blocks use a regular expression to find and remove the 2nd IP. tag soup, and code free questions dont go down well, we expect some effort to have been shown

Comment: I've played with variety of techniques, all of which didn't give me the results I wanted. I didn't post what I used because I didn't want there to be any more confusion. Not to mention I'm pretty new at this, so I was bit gun shy as well.

Answer (score 1):

With this as the input file:

```
$ cat file
XXXXX PYTHONEXP xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxx 12.34.34.34 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxx 12.34.34.34 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
XXXXX PYTHONEXP xxxxxx xxxxxxx 55.44.44.44 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx 55.44.44.44 xxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
XXXXX PYTHONEXP xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx 77.66.66.66 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx 77.66.66.66 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
XXXXX PYTHONEXP xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx 99.88.88.88 xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx 99.88.88.88 xxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
XXXXX PYTHONEXP xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx 22.33.33.33 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx 22.33.33.33 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
XXXXX PYTHONEXP xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx 99.88.88.88 xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx 99.88.88.88 xxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

We can select only those lines that contain `PYTHONEXP` and, for those, remove the second occurrence of an IP address as follows:

```
$ sed -En '/PYTHONEXP/{ s/(( ([[:digit:]]+\.){3}[[:digit:]]+).*)(\2)/\1/; p }' file
XXXXX PYTHONEXP xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxx 12.34.34.34 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
XXXXX PYTHONEXP xxxxxx xxxxxxx 55.44.44.44 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
XXXXX PYTHONEXP xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx 77.66.66.66 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
XXXXX PYTHONEXP xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx 99.88.88.88 xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
XXXXX PYTHONEXP xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx 22.33.33.33 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
XXXXX PYTHONEXP xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx 99.88.88.88 xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

This matches your desired output.

#### How it works

- `-E` tells sed to use the more modern extended regular expressions.
- `-n` tells sed not to print unless we explicitly ask it to.
- `/PYTHONEXP/{ ... }` tells sed to select only those line that match the regex `PYTHONEXP` and, for those lines, apply the commands in curly braces.  In our case, the curly braces contain two commands:

  - `s/old/new/` is a substitution command that, in our case, removes the second occurrence of an IP address from the line.
  - `p` tells sed to print the resulting line.

The substitution command looks like:

```
s/(( ([[:digit:]]+\.){3}[[:digit:]]+).*)(\2)/\1/
   ----------------------------------   ----
                  |                       |
        This matches a space followed     |
        by an IP address                  | 
        (This is saved in group 2.)       |
                                          |
                                       This matches another
                                       occurrence of the same IP


  --------------------------------------
               |
      This matches a space and an IP
      followed by anything and this
      is save as group 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

are the duplicate lines common? the xxx u have mentioned in file.
if so below should work in bash
**cat filename | grep -i  PYTHONEXP | uniq**